# jqueryUI close hangs

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Using jQueryUI and with the dialog and calling it below when Ok is click it hangs. I believe it is being closed correctly? Is this a threading issue where the UI is in a different thread and I am expecting it to block the current thread and resume when closed? If so how can block the execution of Javascript until the jQueryUI is closed?

```
<div id="confirm00" class="ui-helper-hidden"
         title="Alert00">
        <p th:text="#{vendorEDI}"></p>
</div>

function confirm00(){
    $("#confirm00").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        width: 400,
        buttons: [
            {
                text: "Ok",
                icon: "ui-icon-heart",
                click: function() {
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                }
            }
        ]
    })
    $("#confirm00").dialog('open');
}
```

To answer the question below, it is called in button click event below.  The intention is to block to inform and then prevent default.

```
 if ($('#ediFile')[0].files.length === 0) {
        confirm00();
        $("#uploadForm input[name='processed']").val("");
        $("#uploadForm input[name='processedNonce00']").val("");
        $('#uploadForm').submit(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
        });
        return;
```

Sorry for the segment, below is the entire function that gets called on a button click.  The dialog presents, clears but the browser is frozen.

```
function noEDI(choice) {
    var processType=$("#uploadForm select[name='processType']").val();
    $("#showReports01 input[name='processType']").val(processType);
    $("#showReports02 input[name='processType']").val(processType);
    if ($('#ediFile')[0].files.length === 0) {
        confirm00();
        $("#uploadForm input[name='processed']").val("");
        $("#uploadForm input[name='processedNonce00']").val("");
        $('#uploadForm').submit(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
        });
        return;
    } else if (isEdiXML() == "false") {
        confirm00();
        $("#uploadForm input[name='processed']").val("");
        $("#uploadForm input[name='processedNonce00']").val("");
        $('#uploadForm').submit(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
        });
        return;
    } else {
        if ($('#creditmemos').length > 0)
            $('#creditmemos').remove();
        if ($('#reorders').length > 0)
            $('#reorders').remove();
        $("#uploadForm input[name='subscriber_s']").val(subscriber);
        var shortName = $("#subscriberFrm select[name='shortName']").val();
        $("#uploadForm input[name='shortName']").val(shortName);
        $("#btnExtracts input[name=ediOriginalFileName]").val(originalFileName);
        uploadDialog();  //modal jqueryUI.
        $('#uploadForm').submit();
    }
}
```

Comment: *" Is this a threading issue"* ... No. Any errors in dev tools console when it hangs? Is `confirm00()` being called more than once?

Comment: Your code works fine - [working JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dont_panic/4mbeqt3c/). How are you calling `confirm00()` to initially open the dialog?

Comment: I don't fully understand the structure of your code, but I see 2 problems.  1) You mention `confirm00()` "*is called in button click event*".  So every time that button is clicked, `confirm00()` fires, and the dialog is re-instantiated, ie a new one is created.  You really should instantiate your dialog just once, independently of any event handlers, conditions, or user action.  All you want to do on click is open it.  [Updated JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dont_panic/4mbeqt3c/).

Comment: 2) Similar problem with your `submit` handler - you are adding a new handler every time the button is clicked.  They are *added* to the existing stack of handlers, the new one does not replace the old one.  They will *all* fire next time the button is clicked.  This probably doesn't cause problems in this case, but is potentially confusing, and messy.